# Apple store app - rules on external links / url

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am a bit confused concerning the rules of external links / url.
I am making a Native app. Its a free app. I would like to put it in the Apple store.

Its a cooking app with recipes and instruction videos. The app links to a youtube instruction video on how to cook the dish you have selected.

Example: They push the button. They will leave the app and go directly to my youtube cooking video. (I am new to programming and I think this would probably be the easiest way to do it)

Will they reject my app because I link to my youtube video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, that is definitely allowed.**  You can open the page in a `UIWebView` so it remains in the app, or have the page open in the Safari browser.

You can link to as many websites as you would like, as long as you aren't somehow breaking copyright (you aren't) or linking to inappropriate sites.

If I could make a suggestion, if you have not learned about the `UIWebView` class yet, you should look into it for this.  It allows you to load web pages from within your app.  This would be a lot better for you because users could remain in your app while watching your youtube cooking videos.  There are plenty of tutorials available online, and the official documentation is  [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: if i liked to a youtube video that is not my own. is it still ok.

Comment: Yes that is fine as well!  Look at my updated answer for more information on how to go about doing this

Comment: I have another question. I really want to put my app on the Apple app store. If i just made a native app which is a button that linked to a web app, which is my app. Would that be ok?

Comment: Is the entire app just a button?  Apple probably wouldn't like that.  They are really intense about making sure every app fits their expectations on look and performance.

Comment: The right method would be to make a native app tailored to the iPhone.  Like Facebook has a mobile site, but they also have an app that is a little easier to use on the iPhone.

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. But i think you are right. Thanks so much for your time and the link.